# Deleting an Oracle database without connecting to it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have two databases which were created using `dbca`.
I made some changes in the second database, and I can't login to that database anymore, and, of course, I can't delete it by using `dbca`.

I am using Centos 5 and Oracle 10g Release 2.

How can I delete a database manually without impacting another dababase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [René Nyffenegger's blog](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/drop_database.html):

> Since 10g, It is possible to drop a database in Oracle 10g with the new SQL statement `drop database`…
>
> The command gets rid of datafiles online redo log files, controlfiles and spfile…
>
> ```
> shutdown abort;
> startup mount exclusive restrict; 
> drop database;
> exit
> ```
>
> Requirements:
>
> . database must be closed
>     . exclusively mounted
>     . restricted

If you do not have a password, you should still be able to connect from the console, eg:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Answer (score 1):

If by database you mean tablespaces and schemas, and if your databases are based on different datafiles, you can remove tablespaces and datafiles like this:

```
DROP TABLESPACE tablespace_name
 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES 
   CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ;
```

If you want to delete entire database itself:

```
drop database database_name including backups
```

The secondary db will not be impacted unlesss you have cross references using database links, in which case some procedures or views will become invalid.